# Is "оформить товар двумя частями" correct?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова

You're ordering a product and the seller offers you a installment plan. You want to pay it off in two installments.

Прошу вас ***оформить*** это товар *двумя частями*

Прошу вас ***выпустит*** это товар *в два рассрочки*

I've seen "в рассрочку" and "по частям". **I want to keep it formal.**

Answer (score 2):

> Прошу вас оформить рассрочку двумя платежами

would work fine.

If you want to go full legalese, you would use:

> Прошу вас оформить продажу в рассрочку, с уплатой цены товара двумя платежами.

*Уплата цены* may sound peculiar, but this is the way the law uses it.

*Выпустить* doesn't mean "to sell". There's a word, *отпустить*, literally "relinquish", which, through a chain of metonymies, did come to mean "to sell". But it's usually only used when there's more to the sale than a demand from a solvent buyer (for instance if say, the goods are rationed or the sale needs to be authorized), and it's more about the transfer of goods rather than the sale contract, so it's not the word of choice for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

- Я хотел бы оплатить этот заказ по частям.
- Я хотел бы приобрести это в рассрочку.
- Прошу вас оформить этот заказ с оплатой по частям / в рассрочку.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep close to the sentences suggested in the question, then this one could be salvaged:

> Прошу вас **оформить** это**т** товар двумя частями

"Двумя частями" is a good expression, somewhat frequently used in newspapers and magazines, see real examples (highlighted orange) in [these corpus search results](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?gramm2=ins&gramm3=ins&lang=ru&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&lex1=%2A%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%7C+%2A%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%7C+%2A%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0+%7C+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%2A+%7C+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%2A+%7C+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%2A+%7C+%2A%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%7C+%2A%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%7C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%2A+%7C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%7C+%2A%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%7C+%2A%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&lex2=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0&lex3=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&max2=5&max3=1&min2=1&min3=1&mode=paper&p=0&parent1=0&parent2=0&parent3=0&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexgramm).
But you should carefully choose the verb so that it would be clear that you want *the payment* to come in two parts, not the product.

- Прошу вас **принять оплату** за товар двумя частями.
- Я бы хотел **оплатить** товар двумя частями.
- Мне было бы удобно **перечислить** полную сумму двумя частями.

All three examples above would work with "[двумя платежами](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=paper&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&noaccent=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)" too. On one hand "двумя платежами" is less ambiguous since it's already about the payment. On the other hand it would repeat the same root twice in a sentence (оплата-платежами), which might be considered a less-than-perfect style.

Alas, the second suggested sentence, "в две рассрочки" is impossible. "Рассрочка" already means the process of paying the debt in chunks. "Две рассрочки" implies that you're asking for two installemnt *plans*, rather than for two installemnts.

---

Another good translation for "installment" is "**взнос**". It's formal enough and can be used in legal documents, particulary in insurance premium installemnt plans.

- Прошу вас разбить оплату на два взноса.
- Мне хотелось бы оплатить товар в рассрочку двумя взносами.

Answer (score 0):

> Прошу вас выпустит это товар в два рассрочки

This is ungrammatical: выпустит is 3rd person (he/she), but вас is 2nd person, два is masculine, рассрочки is feminine. Overall, it's unclear what's being said here.

*выпустить* means "to manufacture, produce". What did you meant to say?

Comment: By выпустить he meant issue. Like "This document was issued by the goverment" дата выпус... He is trying to say if they can issue, оформить the docyment (payment check)